# Specify Width and Height of Plot

Tags: graphics, r, par

I have a panel containing three plots. How can I use `par` to specify the width and height of the main panel so it is always at a fixed size?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I usually set this at the start of my session with `windows.options`:

```
windows.options(width=10, height=10)

# plot away
plot(...)
```

If you need to reset to "factory settings":

```
dev.off()
windows.options(reset=TRUE)

# more plotting
plot(...)
```

Comment: This is Windows specific, I think.

Comment: Does not work on Mac OSX:

`Browse[1]> windows.options(width=10, height=10)
Error in windows.options(width = 10, height = 10) : 
  could not find function "windows.options"`

Answer (score 34):

You do that in the device, e.g.

```
x11(width=4, height=6)
```

and similarly for the file-based ones

```
pdf("/tmp/foo.pdf", width=4, height=6)
```

You can read the physical size via `par("cin")` etc but not set it.

Comment: For completeness, `width` and `height` are specified in inch.

Comment: As @fbmd mentioned, but also if you specify unit='in', you must also specify res='xx' where xx is 72, for example.

Answer (score 18):

Neither solution works in **Jupyter notebooks**. Here is a general approach that works in any environment:

```
options(repr.plot.width=6, repr.plot.height=4)
```

Just keep the following function handy:

```
set_plot_dimensions <- function(width_choice, height_choice) {
        options(repr.plot.width=width_choice, repr.plot.height=height_choice)
        }
```

EXAMPLE

**Data**

```
 x <-  c(37.50,46.79,48.30,46.04,43.40,39.25,38.49,49.51,40.38,36.98,40.00,38.49,37.74,47.92,44.53,44.91,44.91,40.00,41.51,47.92,36.98,43.40)
```

Call function with dimensions, and draw plot:

```
set_plot_dimensions(6, 4)
show_distribution(x, 'test vector')
```

[image]

```
set_plot_dimensions(16, 4)
show_distribution(x, 'test vector')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think a ggplot based answer is needed here...

**If you want to save a figure as you have seen in the preview window**, this would be the best practice:

1. ggplot first

```r
 ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) +
           geom_point(size=2, shape=23)
```

2. Check the figure in Rstudio Plots window, if not satisfied, click Zoom, drag the pop-out window to your preferred size
3. right click the figure and choose Inspect element

then you see the line

```html
<img id="plot" width="100%" height="100%" src="plot_zoom_png?width=214&amp;height=151">
```

The above line suggests that your best width is 2.14 and best height at 1.51

4. ggsave() what you have just seen

```r
ggsave(filename = "foo3.png",width = 2.14, height = 1.51, dpi = 300)
# set the dpi as journal requirement, now the dpi only changes image quality, not image content, default unit is 'in' inch
```

**If you want to shape your figure to fit a journal's need**, this would be the best practice:

1. Obtain parameters from the journal, for example width = 180mm, height =185mm following Nature [Link](https://www.nature.com/documents/NRJs-guide-to-preparing-final-artwork.pdf)
2. Create a new Figure window using that parameters

```r
# you only need noRStudioGD=TRUE if using Rstudio
dev.new(width = 90, height = 180, unit = "mm",noRStudioGD=TRUE)
#note that a new window will appear in your task bar
```

3. plot() or ggplot() and preview the figure in that window
4. ggsave() what you have seen

```r
ggsave(filename = "foo3.png",width = 90, height = 180, unit = "mm", dpi = 300)
```