# Making a graph narrower by setting the margins

Tags: r

How do I go about making the width of a graph narrower by adjusting the margins of the plotting device?

For example with:

```
plot(1:40)
```

Is there a parameter I can use to control the margins?

Comment: Since `graph` refers to a specific mathematical construct, in this case it's more appropriate to say `plot` or `figure`.

Comment: @Spacedman is correct.  The plot will fill the open device.  If you're working in an IDE, simply resize the plot window.  Otherwise use `windows()` or `x11()`

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279003/specify-width-and-height-of-plot

Comment: @Spacedman Only if the OP is good at converting pixels on screen to an absolute size of plot. Even the suggestion to control the size of the *device* won't control the size of the region where data gets plotted, if that is what the OP mean by "width". There could be real nuance to this question so I am only hovering on the **-1** vote at the moment hoping that they come back and clarify what they mean by "width".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`par` is used to set the graphical parameters.

`mar` gives the number of lines of margin to be specified on the four sides of the plot. A numerical vector of the form c(bottom, left, top, right).

To make the plot narrower:

```
par(mar=c(5,10,5,10))
plot(1:40)
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers given, other plotting devices, like `png()` and `pdf()` have `width` and `height` options.

```
png(filename=..., width=200, heigth=800, units="px")
plot(1:40)
dev.off()
```

Comment: The visual devices (`x11()`, `windows()`, and `quartz()`, as well as the generic `dev.new()`) also take the parameters of `height` and `width`.

Answer (score 0):

As your question is almost opaque as to what you mean by "width" - the width of the device, the width of the region containing the data points, etc? - I'll put out another option, parameter `pin`:

```
layout(1:2)
plot(1:10)
op <- par(pin = c(3,2)) ## 3" by 2" high
plot(1:10)
par(op)
layout(1)
```

which produces

[image]

when used with

```
png("par-pin-plot.png", units = "in", height = 8, width = 5, res = 100)
...plot code...
dev.off()
```

If you then use parameter `mai` to set the margin sizes in inches as well, you can control the *exact* width of the plot region, margins, and overall figure.